# Python 2D List issue

Tags: python, python-3.x

now I have a list like this:

```
list1 = [
[1, 2, 3, 4],
[5, 6, 7, 8],
[9, 1, 2, 3],
[4, 5, 6, None]
]
```

And then define a function:

```
def thefunction(position: tuple[int, int], board: Board) -> bool:
```

Now I want this function return a bool value, returns **True** if the given (row, column) position is "None", otherwise, return **False**:

```
thefunction((0,0), list1)
False

thefunction((3,3), list1)
True
```

The trouble I encounter is that I don't know how to do the comparison of the (row, column) information of the list and then output bool value.

Comment: Don't use built-in names (`list`) for variable names.

Comment: what is the body of 'thefunction'?

Comment: What is the definition of the type `Board`?

Comment: Board = list[list[Optional[int]]]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `tuple[int, ...]` for your type hint for position:

```
from typing import Optional


def is_none(position: tuple[int, ...], board: list[list[Optional[int]]]) -> bool:
    if not len(board) or not all(len(row) == len(board) for row in board):
        raise ValueError('Invalid board, must be square.')
    board_rows, board_cols = len(board), len(board[0])
    if len(position) != 2:
        raise ValueError('Position must have exactly two values.')
    row, col = position
    if 0 <= row < board_rows and 0 <= col < board_cols:
        return board[row][col] is None
    raise ValueError('Position must be on board.')


def main() -> None:
    board = [
        [1, 2, 3, 4],
        [5, 6, 7, 8],
        [9, 1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6, None],
    ]
    print(is_none((0, 0), board))
    print(is_none((3, 3), board))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Output:**

```
False
True
```

Comment: Thanks, now I got how to deal with like this!